# MongoDB denying API access, while console shell works

Tags: mongodb, permissions, authentication, java

I am a MongoDB newbie, with a MongoDB instance running on a Ubuntu machine.

If I login onto the machine's console and run `mongo -u username -p password databasename` I have permissions for the database `databasename` to create and drop collections, insert documents and remove them. I have successfully tested these operations.

However, if I try to insert a document (into *the same database using the same user credentials*) **using the MongoDB API from a Java program** (running on the same server), I get error 13:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13: 
'not authorized on databasename to execute command { insert: "collectionName" ...
```

My Java code (works well when running on my local machine for another MongoDB instance without authentication):

```
...
ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(serverName, portNo);
MongoCredential mongoCredential = 
     MongoCredential.createCredential(username, DB_NAME, password.toCharArray());
mongoClient = new MongoClient(...
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("databasename");
mongoCollection = db.getCollection("collectionName");
this.mongoCollection.insert(...                          <-- CAUSES EXCEPTION
....
```

What could be the cause of this error, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Auth is on, so you have to use username and password on mongoclient

Comment: @Antonis: The Java program does use username and password. I have edited the question to better reflect this.

Comment: Is the enableLocalhostAuthBypass set to on? I suspect you are using the localhost exception when trying to access via shell. http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/core/authentication/#localhost-exception . The user is not configured correctly but you bypass it from the localhost.

Comment: @Antonis: Interesting! How can I check the value of enableLocalhostAuthBypass?

Comment: This will reveal the running configuration db.adminCommand( { getParameter : "*" }  ) You can change the * with enableLocalhostAuthBypass but the output is usually short and not worth it.

Comment: @Antonis: Thanks, great command. I tested it successfully on my local MongoDB instance. However, I don't have sufficient rights to execute this command on my production server, but I will instruct the admin to explore this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this problem was likely a [MongoDB server configuration issue](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp), relating to IP address binding. [Changing 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost#20778887) resolved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

My problem got solved by restarting the app. I am using PM2 as process manager.